# Open ​​​​Redirect

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hyperlinks

[*StackOverflow bought the hyphenated site*](https://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&returnurl=http://1083999372)!

</kidding>

The URL `https://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&returnurl=?` will redirect to any URL in any domain.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Look at the URL.  http://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&returnurl=http://experts-exchange.com  This is a security hole.

Comment: I did, but where is the URL from? You should specify it in your post

Comment: @Kop: You can use this URL in social engineering attacks as a legitimate-looking URL that redirects to an evil site.

Comment: I would re-write your post to better highlight the bug.

Comment: @SLaks: how can it possibly be "legitimate-looking" if it clearly states the return url? Google has security holes too then: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.experts-exchange.com%2F&ei=pzhHTJqHFcWOjAeK68H1Bg&usg=AFQjCNE2rYSIdzEWwck-nFIf8qblbQGjIg&sig2=pWlzfTH3uX-2bRkoKDlzwQ (and with google's it's harder to understand what it does)

Comment: @Justin:​ Done.

Comment: Ah, the memories... http://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&blah=123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789&returnurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DoHg5SJYRHA0

Comment: @Slaks, how can this be a security issue, besides sending people to harmful sites?

Comment: @Justin: It can be used in phishing emails as social engineering

Comment: After the update, "StackOverflow bought the hyphenated site!" returns a blank page that says "true."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect here is now only valid for sites in our network, this change will go out in a build tonight, for example:

**Invalid:** `http://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&returnurl=http://www.cornify.com`

**Valid:** `http://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&returnurl=http://www.serverfault.com`

Invalid URLs (to any other domains) simply won't cause a redirect anymore.

Comment: hmmm, this still fails Open Redirect attacks, http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=http://myfakestackoverflow.com/login

Answer (score 5):

Imagine receiving this email (also, pretend you're dumb and likely to fall for phishing scams, but stay with me here):

> To: Valued Stack Overflow user
>
> From: Jeff Atwood, stackoverflow.com
>
> Hey there, [blank]! We had a massive database failure, and unfortunately, our user database got all messed up. Thankfully, though, the fix is easy - all we need you to do is log in to the website. We've set up a special page to help make this repair easy, so please visit [Stack Overflow account repair](https://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&returnurl=http://evil.stackunderflow.com) and sign in with your OpenID, and everything will be fixed for your account.

That "Stack Overflow account repair" page, which appears to reside on stackoverflow.com *actually* points to an evil phisher, who's site is http://evil.stackunderflow.com. Stack Underflow happens to look identical to Stack Overflow, and when you sign in, the nefarious owner of Stack Underflow is able to transfer all of your rep points to his account!! Nooooo!!!!

Will this particular scenario ever happen? No, but I think it illustrates a point - open redirects are something to think about, since even when I look at the url, it looks like it's at stackoverflow.com, unless I read all the way to the end and see the evil.stackunderflow.com address.

---

To make this more evil, hover over the URL in Chrome! Chrome shows you the first portion of the URL, and after a second of hovering, **then** expands to show the whole URL. The URL is just long enough that it first displays this:

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&returnurl=..."
```

[Chrome screenshot http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7921/chromehover.png](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7921/chromehover.png)

Comment: Okay, when I wrote this, I just made up the stackunderflow.com address. I had no idea it is *actually* a website! Too bad it's broken.

Comment: But that's the beauty of OpenID! The most they could get would be an auth token IF you reauthorized it. That's one of the reasons why you get directed to your OpenID site and authorize there! So even if you're on a phishing site the most they can get is your base open id url. :)

Comment: I guess the best example against this is the Google example given in the comment above to the post.

Answer (score 1):

This link better highlights the real security issue:

> [http://stackoverflow.com/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=128&returnurl=http://www.wikipedia.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0)

Comment: Not really. I can *see* youtube in the message text. It's worse when the URL is shortened - think, goatse trolling on /.

Comment: @Shog, see my edit

Comment: My vulnerability can be used in phishing emails with URL-encoding.  Rickrolling posts can be fixed by moderators.

Comment: @Slaks, I guess I don't see the difference.

Comment: @Justin: I think he's saying that users might trust a URL that appears to be from SO *outside of SO* more than they'd trust, say, a random obfuscated URL.

Comment: @Shog9: Exactly.

Comment: @SLaks and @Shog, I get it.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Isn't this a problem with hyperlinks and HTML more than anything else?

Comment: @Changeling: no... There are plenty of problems caused by URLs that appear to go to one site and actually go to another, but this one requires cooperation from the apparent target in the form of a redirect to the actual target. Since SO isn't normally *that kind of site*, it's understandable that even savvy users might not expect it.

Comment: @Shog9: But if you look at the source of the hyperlink in this particular example (above answer), there is no redirect going on.. the text of the a href is the stackoverflow URL but the a href is actually youtube. I don't see how that is a redirect. Maybe you could explain further because I must be missing something....

Comment: @Changeling: woops, I thought you were talking about SLaks' issue rather than jjnguy's. Yes, linking to one thing with text of another is a HTML thing - that's why most browsers display the actual URL in the status bar.

Comment: @Shog9: No problem :) Lost in translation

Comment: LOL that was funny

Answer (score 0):

On any of the stack overflow sites it is pretty easy to disguise one url as another.  Simply use the following syntax:

```
[http://fakeUrlThatLooksHarmless.com](http://rick-roll_d.com)
```

Displays as:

[http://fakeUrlThatLooksHarmless.com](http://rick-roll_d.com)

Comment: My vulnerability can be used in phishing emails with URL-encoding.

Comment: Yes, true, but when I hover over the link, I can see it goes straight to your rick-roll_d.com link. Hover over one of the evil links, and I see "stackoverflow.com/blahblahblah".